# Tcl'Tk - непонятное поведение if else в теле команды foreach

Tags: foreach, if, tcl

Этот код должен по идее создавать список заполненный случайными числами (кроме 0), а вместо повтора чисел вставлять "".
Но значением $k == $valume постоянно является False ...
Как сделать так, что бы при повторах было значение True.

..........................................................................................................................................................

Да, спасибо, но дело в том что при значении set order {"ЗНАЧЕНИЕ"} получается бесконечный цикл, а при set order {} -> " order = 'пусто' "
..........................................................................................................................................................
Команда ldelete в теле foreach вроде бы должна "ликвидировать" все "".
Почему этого не происходит (удаляется только одна ""), и как это исправить.
..............................................................................................................................................................
Это мне понятно, но ldelete работает в цикле, так почему она не удаляет все ""!
..............................................................................................................................................................
Большое спасибо за set order [ldelete $order ""] (команду ldelete  взял из книжки Брент Уэлш, 4-е изд.), а также за остальную помощь - теперь код работает корректно!
Но не надо расслабляться, конечное кол-во чисел < А - чую, нужна будет рекурсия!!
..........................................................................................................................................................
Команда !spisok исполняется 2 раза - т. е. рекурсии нету! Почему? И как это исправить (может ли иметь к этому отношение № версии Tcl которую я использую)
Или тут лучше использовать цикл. (Я хочу что бы в итоговом списке число чисел = а)
..........................................................................................................................................................
!Spisok  $t  $order - невнимательность пополам с неопытностью.
Осталось сделать так чтобы в результирующем списке не было повторов!
...................................................................................................................................................................
Я сам себе ответил на вопрос который задал в тексте проги, но не знаю как эту    погрешность исправить, так что мне нужен просто код!

```
 proc Vvod {a} {
           global t
           puts stdout { Vvedite a:}
           set a [gets stdin]
           set t [format "%d" $a] 
        }
      proc Ldelete {list value} {
            set ix [lsearch -exact $list $value]
            if {$ix >= 0} {
               return [lreplace $list $ix $ix]
            } else {
               return $list
            }
        }
      proc Bez_X {order} {  
        foreach valume $order {
          set m [lsearch -all $order $valume]
          set y [lrange $m 1 end]
        foreach val $y { 
          lset order $val X
                  }
          set order [Ldelete $order X]         
        }   
          return $order
    }         
      proc Spisok {t} {
        for {set i 1} {$i <= $t } {incr i} {
          set j [expr {round(rand()*$t)}]
        if {$j == 0} {
            set k [expr {$j + 1}]
    } else {
          set k $j
            }   
          lappend order $k  
        }    
          puts stdout "order = $order"   
          set order [Bez_X $order]
          puts stdout "order1 = $order"   
          return $order     
          }  
      proc !Spisok {order t} {
          set dlina [llength $order]
        if {$dlina < $t} {
          set order1 [Spisok [expr $t - $dlina]]
          set order [concat $order $order1]
          puts stdout "order2 = $order"
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------      
          set order [Bez_X $order ] 
    #Почему при присутствии этой команды Bez_X получается бесконечный цикл? 
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------  
          puts stdout "order3 = $order"     
          !Spisok $order $t
    } else {
        return $order
       }
    }
        while 1 {
          Vvod a
          set order [Spisok $t]
          set x [!Spisok $order $t]
          puts stdout "x = $x"   
        }
```

Comment: Вместо  foreach valume order должно быть foreach valume $order. Как есть сейчас - вы пытаетесь пройти foreach по списку из одного элемента - строки order.

Comment: Вы внутри цикла по $order добавляете к этому списку новые значения командами типа lappend order $k. Потому цикл и получается бесконечный. А если список исходно пустой, то тело цикла не выполняется ни разу, список так и остается пустым.

Comment: Командой ldelete $order "" вы и удаляете только значение "".

Comment: А вообще должно быть set order [ldelete $order ""], судя из того, как функция ldelete написана.

Comment: Видимо, на втором шаге рекурсии $dlina >= $t